# Floated list appearing outside <div>

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to put a list inside of a `<div>` so that I can change the background of the div and make the list be a navbar.

The problem is that the items in the list actually appear in a horizontal row below the div.  I don't know why this is - they are child elements and should float to the left of each other inside the `<ul>` element which is inside the `<div>`, or at least that's my understanding of it.

When I remove `float: left`, they work fine, but appear in list format instead of side by side like I want.

Why is this occuring?

Here is the PHP code that creates the HTML.

```
echo <<<_HDOC
    <div id="header">
        Title
    </div>

    <div id="linkbar">
        <ul id="links">
_HDOC;

if ($_COOKIE['main'] == "")
    echo  "<li class='menulinks'>Register</li>  <li class='menulinks'>Login</li>";
else{
    $cookieparts = explode('&', $_COOKIE['main']);
    echo "<li class='menulinks'>Welcome $cookieparts[0]</li>  <li class='menulinks'>Logout</li>";
}

echo "<li class='menulinks'>About</li>  </ul></div>";
```

And here is the CSS code

```
#linkbar{
        padding: 5px;
        background-color: #31574A;
        color: white;
    }

#links{
        width: 100%;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

.menulinks{
        float: left;
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `clear` to at the end of the list.

***Why do I have to do this?***

*A container element's height does not automatically adjust to a child element that is floated. When something is floated, it is removed from the traditional flow. In order to resolve it, you must use a clear*

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uHPr8/1):

**CSS**

```
li 
{
   float: left;
} 
.clearFix
{
   clear: both;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearFix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @eZakto Definitely not bad practice.

Comment: Well, a div inside an ul was a bad practice. :)

Comment: Where is there a `<div>` inside of a `<ul>`

Comment: @Gabe can't you just add .clearfix to the `ul` and not have to add another element?

Comment: @paislee No, you can not do that.

Comment: Well, this works, and I can see why, but could you explain just so I can make sure I've got a grasp of what's going on here?

Comment: A container element's height does not automatically adjust to a child element that is floated. When something is floated, it is removed from the traditional flow. In order to resolve it, you must use a clear

Answer (score 0):

Floated elements don't push their containers by default.

You should research css clearfix.

In your example, maybe something like this will do the trick:

```
#links:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Try it with that!

Regards.

Comment: I really don't understand what you did here.  Could you explain it a little better?

Comment: Search for clearfix. http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Answer (score 0):

Add `<div style="clear:both"></div>` before you close the div#linkbar

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vEkqG/)

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution (that doesn't require adding new elements) is to simply add `overflow:hidden;` to the element containing the floated elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/UcqfA/